# C# Sharp List (Out of Range Exception Error)

Tags: c#

I would like some help on my program. It is supposed to randomize the seating order of my class. However, I keep getting an "Out of Range Exception".Although all indices start with 0, I tried but was not able to fix it. How do I get rid of this. If possible, could it be possible to not repeat the elements in the list? I apologize for my inaccurate question, but here is my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.AddRange(new String[]
        {
            "Daria", "Denisa", "Erica",
            "Merlin", "Nicoletta", "Mia",
            "Lilian", "Karel", "Luveesh",
            "Milan", "Oliver","Tea",
            "Carlos", "Raneem", "Marsha",
            "Uros", "Oguzhan"
        });

        Random random = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'x' then hit 'Enter' to exit");

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userInput == "x")
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Table 1: " + "" + list[random.Next(1, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(2, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 2: " + "" + list[random.Next(3, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(4, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 3: " + "" + list[random.Next(5, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(6, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 4: " + "" + list[random.Next(7, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(8, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 5: " + "" + list[random.Next(9, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(10, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 6: " + "" + list[random.Next(11, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(12, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 7: " + "" + list[random.Next(13, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(14, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 8: " + "" + list[random.Next(15, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(16, list.Count)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Table 9: " + "" + list[random.Next(17, list.Count)]);
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try this:                int lastIndex = list.Count - 1;
                for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Table {0}: {1}, {2}",i+1, list[random.Next(i, lastIndex)], list[random.Next(Math.Min(i+1,lastIndex), lastIndex)]);
                }

Comment: I will surely try this, and I will see if it works :)

Comment: The list has 17 items, its last valid index is 16.  Kabloom on random.Next(17, 17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list` contains 17 elements, where the first is accessed with `list[0]`
 and the last with `list[16]`. Within the last line of your foreach loop ..

```
//                                   <------------ here ------------>
Console.WriteLine("Table 9: " + "" + list[random.Next(17, list.Count)];
```

.. you used `random.Next(min, max)` to generate a random number. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) points out that `min` is the inclusive lower bound of the random number and `max` is the exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. So the problem is, that you tried to create a random number with 17 (inclusive) as `min` and the lists count, which is also 17 (exlusive), as `max`. The generated random number therefore was 17. As C#-lists are zero based, accessing `list[17]` threw the mentioned exception.
 Modifying the code within the `foreach` loop like ..

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Table 1: " + "" + list[random.Next(0, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(1, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 2: " + "" + list[random.Next(2, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(3, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 3: " + "" + list[random.Next(4, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(5, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 4: " + "" + list[random.Next(6, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(7, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 5: " + "" + list[random.Next(8, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(9, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 6: " + "" + list[random.Next(10, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(11, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 7: " + "" + list[random.Next(12, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(13, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 8: " + "" + list[random.Next(14, list.Count)] + "," + "" + list[random.Next(16, list.Count)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Table 9: " + "" + list[random.Next(15, list.Count)]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

.. should do the trick.

Comment: If anyone still online on this post, kindly test code(if one has enough time) and see if they could make all names different, because some repeat...

Comment: So all have to be random, but non repeating

Comment: @L.Purswani, and actually you're not using the `item` variable at all.

Comment: Test comment here

Comment: @derloopkat do I have to? What is it for?

Comment: `foreach` is for iterating through items of the list. If you don't need it, just use `for` like in the code I've posted above

Answer (score 2):

C# is 0 Indexed, start at 0 not at 1.

Comment: I tried starting from 0 as well, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Your max. random number should be 16

Comment: Is it possible to go over 16??

Comment: But if you test the code...some of the names repeat, could someone help with that?